# Copy NPM module/library to distribution folder using Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

Most web applications these days include various prebuilt libraries e.g. Backbone.js.

I want, when I compile my web application with Gulp, to output a single compressed JavaScript file of the library/module I installed using NPM e.g. `backbone-min.js`.

For example, when you install Backbone.js from NPM the following is installed into the `node_modules` folder:

```
.
├── backbone
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── backbone-min.js
│   ├── backbone-min.map
│   ├── backbone.js
│   └── package.json
```

I want to be able to run `gulp compile` and get the following result in my web application distribution folder:

```
.
├── index.html
├── scripts
│   ├── backbone-min.js // this is the file I want to copy or generate
│   ├── main.min.js
```

The way I see it Gulp either needs to either:

- compile and minify the library/module and write it to a file called `backbone-min.js` to the `scripts` folder, or
- copy the `backbone-min.js` in the backbone module folder to the `scripts` folder.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: I think 2nd option is better. why do you want to compile, if you already have -min.js file.

Comment: But how do you get Gulp to copy files within a module

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gulp Copying Files from one Directory to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355907/gulp-copying-files-from-one-directory-to-another)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer**

[gulp-useref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref) concatenates all the file references in your main **.html** file encapsulated by `<!--build:js /lib.js-->` for javascript files and `<!--build:css /lib.css-->` followed by `<!--endbuild-->`

The result will be:

```
index.html
├── scripts
│   ├── backbone-min.js // this is the file I want to copy or generate
│   ├── main.min.js
```

as you and every good developer wants it to be.

**Long Answer**

My recommendation would be to use [Bower](https://bower.io/) as your app dependencies manager and [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) as your development dependencies manager.

Use [gulp-wiredep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-wiredep) to automatically inject dependencies as you install/uninstall them and that way you don't have to maintain library css and js files in your index.html.

Uset [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject) to automatically inject your own css and js files as your add/remove them. This will result in never **ever** having to maintain application dependencies manually.

With wiredep, inject and useref you never have to touch your dependencies again.

This is what my index header and end of body look like:

```
 <!---------------------------- Bower Managed Styles ----------------------------->

<!--build:css css/lib.css-->
<!--bower:css-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/..."

<!--endbower -->
<!--endbuild -->

<!---------------------------- Application Styles ------------------------------->

<!--build:css css/app.css-->
<!--inject:css-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="content/css/bootstrap ..."

<!--endinject-->
<!--endbuild-->


 <!--------------------------- Bower Managed Javascript ------------------------->

    <!--build:js js/lib.js-->
    <!--bower:js -->

    <script src="../bower_components/ ..."> </script>

    <!--endbower -->
    <!--endbuild -->

    <!-------------------------- Application Javascript --------------------------->

    <!--build:js js/app.js-->
    <!--inject:js-->

    <script src="app/ ..."> </script>

    <!--endinject-->
    <!--inject:templates:js-->
    <!--endinject-->
    <!--endbuild-->
```

The comments are tags used by the tools I just mention in order for them to know where to insert the dependencies of interest.

My application entry is a single template reference. Needless to say I never visit index.html. I never have a reference to a file that does not exist. I never have a file that does not have a reference.